# How to include different html files inside a html file using vue js?

Tags: javascript, php, html, vue.js, vue-component

I know to use require_once() of php but php cannot be used in my project. And I also tried w3-include of w3-schools, but in that case my scripts are not loading.
When I tried to load by js also, the same thing happened. I am very much stuck to procced. Can anybody please help me to proceed.

I used this for js

```
    <script> 
   $(function(){
       $("#includedContent").load("b.html"); 
    });
   </script>
```

For w3-schools I used

```
           <script>
          w3.includeHTML();
           </script>
```

This two have not worked for me. Please provide a solution. It's better if you helped me with vue js?

Comment: `for js` - that depends on the jQuery bloatware library - have you bloated your vue with jquery?

Comment: I am using vue js for ajax requests

Comment: ok, was just correcting your assertion that `$("#includedContent").load("b.html");` is somehow for "js" ... it's for js using the jquery bloat

Comment: Can you please suggest a method in vue js

Comment: No, but [this may help](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-render-html-files-inside-vuejs/16161/4)

Comment: But it doesnot work.

Comment: use `v-html` to put all html code in vuejs

Comment: I have 4 html files as a.html, b.html, c.html and d.html.

Comment: I need to include b.html, c.html, d. html in the main file a.html. Can you please help me out

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to fetch the HTML with ajax and set it to a local variable and then render it using v-html.

This is however not a good way to do things. HTML files are likely to contain the markup for a full page, including html, body and head tags which can mess your markup.

If in your case you have a few different html pages the structure of which is known beforehand, you should use them as Vue templates. HTML can be directly copypasted into the template of the Vue component and it will work.

If on the other hand, you want to use something that let's your users write HTML, you should store it in a database. For example if you have a forum where users write posts that they can style in HTML you can save the markup for the single post in a database and then fetch it and render it with v-html as well.